# Copy node_modules from container to host

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code

I am trying to copy node_modules from my container to host. My host is windows. I need them just to support intellisence in VSCode. But some how I am unable to copy them.

I have node_modules up and running on container, just want them on host. If there is any other method to support intellisence in VSCode that should also be fine.

I tried several methods like entrypoint and volume mount but none of them work.

When trying to do docker cp I get
symlink ..\JSONStream\bin.js ...\node_modules.bin\JSONStream: A required privilege is not held by the client.

Also I tried mounting whole of my project but then somehow "npm install"
breaks.

Comment: open command prompt with administrator privilege then `docker cp container_name:path_to_modules /host_path`

Comment: BTW if your container is Linux based, the npm packages will not work in the widow.

Answer (score 0):

I faced somewhat similar issue . 
You can use mounting mechanism using the syntax -v target:source(inside the container).
That will copy all folders and files to the destination.
Your npm install is breaking probably because of proxy issues . Try removing that and install again using your private internet.